# how to set background color as a clear color of searchbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uisearchbar

I want to make searchbar's background as a clear or looklike navigationbar's color

currently showing [image: searchbar]

how to make the backgroung clear of serach bar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beacause UI SearchBar has got its own background view, which is of black color, if we remove that view then UISearchbar's background will become clear :

```
for (UIView *subview in mySearchBar.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's just create black background i need to show the navigation background color

Comment: Does this work within searchDisplayControllers? I can't get this working with iOS 6.1

Comment: Hope this will help you. [searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]]; Will also work in iOS 7.1

Answer (score 2):

//Search bar(using background image)

```
  UISearchBar* bar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(568, 30, 200, 44)];
     UIImageView* iview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue.png"]];
    iview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44);

    [bar insertSubview:iview atIndex:1];
    [iview release];
    [self.view addSubview:bar];
    [bar release];
```

**OR(using color)**

//Search bar

```
UISearchBar* bar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(568, 30, 200, 44)];

[[[bar subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setAlpha:0.0];

bar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.376f green:.386f blue:.452f alpha:1.0];
    bar.clipsToBounds = YES;
[self.view addSubview:bar];
[bar release];
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the background image for the UISearchBar as follows.

```
[searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]];
```

Now the UISearchBar background color will disappear. Will also work in iOS 7.1

Comment: I found this to be the simplest and cleanest solution. Worked in iOS 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

For Clear the background color (If you want images set then use comment code)

```
for (UIView *subview in searchBar.subviews) 
{
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) 
    {   
       // if You want set iamge then use comment code
      /*  UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:subview.frame];
        bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchBar"]];
        [self.searchBar insertSubview:backgroundView aboveSubview:subview];*/

        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For clearing search bar's background view :

```
[[[self.searchBar subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setHidden:YES];
    for (id subview in self.searchBar.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found in iOS8 that this could worked better for reducing a UISearchBar to just a text field. This will allow you to get rid of the background color.

```
for (UIView *subView in self.searchBar.subviews) {
    for (UIView *secondLevelSubview in subView.subviews) {
        if (![secondLevelSubview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarTextField")]) {
            [secondLevelSubview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with this line :

```
[[ [searchBar subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
[[ [searchBar subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
```

Surely help you out.